# How to export images in *.dat format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save, export

I want to use the MATLAB findcluster tool (Fuzzy Logic Toolbox), but it requires the data to be loaded to be in *.dat format.
Is it possible to export my grayscale images(2D matrices actually) in *.dat through MATLAB? And if yes, could I also export 3D images the same way?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, 
Ziggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to think of the image as just like any other array. Then saving/loading to a .dat file is easy. Here's some sample code:

```
% Open a sample image
testImage = imread('tire.tif');
figure; imshow(testImage)

% Convert to double so the ASCII conversion will work properly
testImage = double(testImage);

% Save the .dat file
save test.dat testImage -ascii

% Load the .dat file we just saved
testImageReopened = load('test.dat');

% Convert back to the original format
testImageReopened = uint8(testImageReopened);
figure; imshow(testImageReopened);
```

I believe it should work similarly for a 3D image, but you might want to try it out to be sure.